# jsp error attempting to access hashmap variable

Tags: java, jsp, syntax-error

I am passing a hashmap to a jsp view as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query")
public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("query") Query query,
        Map<String, Object> model) {
...
HashMap<String, String> serviceRequestData = executeSelect(conn, stmt, query);
model.put("serviceRequestData", serviceRequestData);
...
}
```

and trying to access a value for the key "FN_Contact" in the hashmap as follows in the jsp page:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty ${serviceRequestData[FN_Contact]}}">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        <h5>FirstName:</h5>
        ${serviceRequestData[FN_Contact]}<br>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

In this jsp, I am trying to check if the value is null, if it is then do nothing, otherwise print the data. I am receiving the following syntax error:

```
 javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${empty ${serviceRequestData[FN_Contact]}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSTL` Expression Language,

Use the standard function to check length provided by JSTL functions

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Use the following jsp tags,

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${fn:length(serviceRequestData)>= 1}">
    // Place the code what you want to do

</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    // Nothing to display

</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try like this

```
<c:when test="${empty serviceRequestData[FN_Contact]}">
```